# Accessing the Posts page Content

Tags: loop, content

I have a Posts page set in settings->reading - posts page is set to a page called "notes"

How can I access the title, content & featured image of the page? WP seems to want to access the first post instead of the page.

Answer (score 1):

So you can fetch the id using a get_option call, then access the data from there.

```
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );  
$page_data = get_page( $page_for_posts )  ;
```

Then you can access the properties like this:

```
<?= get_the_post_thumbnail($page_data->ID) ?>
<h1><?= $page_data->post_title ?></h1>
<?= $page_data->post_content ?>
```